# @ConditionalOnBean doesn't work properly with micrometer MeterRegistry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I am trying to expose metrics out of my spring boot application using micrometer.

Following configuration didn't work for some reason:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@AutoConfigureAfter({ MetricsAutoConfiguration.class, CompositeMeterRegistryAutoConfiguration.class })
@ConditionalOnClass(MeterRegistry.class)
@ConditionalOnBean(MeterRegistry.class)
public class SuperTestAutoConfig {
    @Bean
    public Object testBean() {
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

Spring says:

```
SuperTestAutoConfig:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry' (OnClassCondition)
```

But for absolutely the same annotated configuration `JvmMetricsAutoConfiguration` it works perfectly:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@AutoConfigureAfter({ MetricsAutoConfiguration.class, CompositeMeterRegistryAutoConfiguration.class })
@ConditionalOnClass(MeterRegistry.class)
@ConditionalOnBean(MeterRegistry.class)
public class JvmMetricsAutoConfiguration {}
```

Log says:

```
   JvmMetricsAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'prometheusMeterRegistry' (OnBeanCondition)
```

Fully example is here: https://filebin.net/gjxnwwksaqs1x8zg

Comment: Maybe change the question to include the autoconfig detail since that is the key part

Answer (score 3):

The reason was in missing `spring.factories` definition for this autoconfig. After listing this class in `spring.factories` it works perfectly as expected.